# how to pull out the vue-router id I need in "el-table" to navigate the page?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-component, vue-router

I'm sorry, I don't know English well. Hello, tell me how to pull out the vue router id I need in the "el-table" to navigate the page.

```
  <tr v-for="spisok in poluhenie">
        <td>
            <router-link :to="{name: 'protocols_information.edit', params: {id: spisok.dogovor_id}}" >Go</router-link>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

The path in it looks like this:

```
/protocol_information/:id/edit/
```

Here is my code

```
<template>
    <el-table :data="TableData" style="width: 100%">
        <el-table-column prop="id" label="№ ID" width="180" />
        <el-table-column prop="num_contract_reg" label="№ договора" width="240" />
        <el-table-column prop="name_organization_reg" label="Название организации" width="240" />
        <el-table-column label="Operations">
            <template #default="scope">
                <el-button size="small" @click="handleEdit(scope.$index, scope.row)">Edit</el-button>
            </template>
        </el-table-column>
    </el-table>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: "SpisokLabelsComponent",
    data(){
        return{
            TableData: null,
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getPoluhenie()
    },
    methods: {
        getPoluhenie(){
            axios.get('/api/protocolsbd', {
                })
                .then(res => {
                    this.TableData = res.data.data;
                    console.log(res)
                })
        },
        handleEdit(row){
            return this.$router.push({
                path:'/protocol_information/:id/edit/',
                params:{
                    id:row.id
                }
            })
        },
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

I tried to create a method for the button "handleEdit"